# Will my Unit of Work implementation cause memory leak?

Tags: entity-framework

I implemented my repository pattern and unit of work in the following way:

- [How to create a simple data access layer](http://bizvise.com/2012/11/28/how-to-create-a-simple-data-access-layer-using-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework/)
- [How to create unit of work](http://bizvise.com/2012/11/28/how-to-create-a-simple-data-access-layer-unit-of-work-pattern-with-entity-framework/)

and I was asked if create multiple instance of my database (which is the unit of work) will cause **memory leak**? and what are the **downside of such implementation**? or is the implementation done right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should worry about is the creation of the `DbContext` as this is expensive.
I typically use one `DbContext` per request instead of creating multiple `DbContext` instances everywhere.

I store it in the `HttpContext` object and dispose of it at the end of the request.

You can find more info on it [here](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof/learn/alert/multiplesessionsinthesamerequest)

Find below my modified implementation. (original was from the link above and used ObjectContext).

My context class

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Web;
using Fot.Admin.Models;

namespace Context
{
    public static class ContextManager
    {
        internal const string DB = "MY_DB_CONTEXT";

        /// <summary>
        /// Get an instance that lives for the life time of the request per user and automatically disposes.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Model</returns>  
        public static T AsSingleton<T>() where T : DbContext, new()
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Items[DB] = (T)HttpContext.Current.Items[DB] ?? new T();
            return (T)HttpContext.Current.Items[DB];
        }


    }
}
```

My Context Module

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Web;

namespace Context
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Entity Module used to control an Entities DB Context over the lifetime of a request per user.
    /// </summary>
    public class ContextModule : IHttpModule
    {
        private const string DB = ContextManager.DB;


        void context_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dispose();
        }


        #region IHttpModule Members

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if(HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Items[DB] != null)
                {
                    var entitiesContext = (DbContext) HttpContext.Current.Items[DB];

                    entitiesContext.Dispose();
                    HttpContext.Current.Items.Remove(DB);

                }

            }
        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.EndRequest += new EventHandler(context_EndRequest); 
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

In my web.config under `<httpModules>` i add this below.

```
<add name="ContextModule" type="Context.ContextModule" />
```

This ensures that the end_Request is called after every request so you can dispose the context properly.

When you need the DbContext usage is as below.

```
 var Context = ContextManager.AsSingleton<MyDBContext>();
```

Comment: in my unit of work implementation, i have a DbContext property and the same DbContext is passed into the repository constructor. Does that mean i'm using on DbContext?

Comment: and do you have the example of how to store DbContext in HttpContext? thanks.

Comment: This is not correct - DbContext is not expensive to instantiate.

Comment: @Pawel I am not an EF expert by any stretch but i think i'll go with the advice of the vendor of EFProf (link above) :)

Comment: @JeeShenLee I've modifid my answer to include my implementation.

Comment: @JeeShenLee I agree with the pattern. I don't agree with the statement saying that creating DbContext is expensive.